# Issue in rail to rail opamp as buffer

Tags: operational-amplifier, analog, buffer, hardware

I'm using LTC6090IS8E#PBF as buffer. Following is the circuit. Actually my input is 100 V and I'm attenuating it to 60 V using voltage divider. Then 60 V is given to non-inverting input of LTC6090IS8E#PBF which is configured as buffer and hence expected output as 60 V. Following is the circuit.
[image]

With this circuit we have built the PCB and we are not getting expected output.
At pin 3 of U3 I'm expecting input voltage as 60 V but it is coming as 76 V. I'm not able to understand why input voltage is getting changed. I removed U3 then Voltage divider is giving 60 V at junction of pin 3 but when I connect back U3 on PCB the same junction is giving 76 V instead of 60 V.

Can anyone help me to understand how input pin of opamp LTC6090IS8E#PBF influence the voltage divider circuit which is externally connected? It is important to note that this is rail to rail high voltage opamp.

Also opamp is taking 20 mA as supply current instead of 3 mA as stated in datasheet and giving undesired output.

Comment: When you prototyped the circuit before committing to a pc board, did you capture a scope shot of the output?

Comment: Is there any other circuit on your board that could be driving 60V output higher? If the 60V output is driven higher then, it can couple back to the input +IN via the diodes between -IN and +IN. scope shot of the 60V output will be very useful. Is the 100V connected only to U3 and the resistor divider and the caps?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> *Can anyone help me to understand how input pin of opamp
> LTC6090IS8E#PBF influence the voltage divider circuit which is
> externally connected?*

The main issue that I see is the 100 nF capacitor connected from the op-amp output to ground. This is a big no-no for most op-amps and, I see nothing in the [data sheet](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/6090fe.pdf) that justifies the use of a capacitor like this. Normally, an op-amp with an output capacitor like this will turn into an oscillator i.e. go unstable and, this will affect the non-inverting input as shown further down: -

[image]

In fact, on page 1 of the data sheet it says the maximum output capacitance is 200 pF: -

[image]

The reason why the input voltage on pin 3 isn't 60 volts is because of the input protection diodes on the op-amp and, the fact that the output directly routes to pin 2 (the inverting input): -

[image]

So, any error on the output pin of the op-amp can severely affect the signal on the non-inverting input and, given that you are using quite high value resistors to form a potential divider to that pin, this is a likely cause; this and the output being unstable due to the 100 nF capacitor previously mentioned.

> *Also opamp is taking 20 mA as supply current instead of 3 mA as stated
> in datasheet and giving undesired output.*

You are inviting the op-amp to become unstable with the 100 nF output capacitor and, when this happens, all bets are off in reasoning what the output produces.

Comment: I think the answer is spot on. In addition R9 is set at 0 Ohms, so there is effectively  25k Ohm with two back to back diodes between the inputs. R9 should be in the range of 100k Ohm to 500k Ohm.

Comment: @JackCreasey its 250 ohm between the two inputs.

Comment: You are right ...I misread the datasheet. .

Comment: @Andyaka and JackCreasey Thanks for taking time and responding. Yes I shouldn't have connected high value capacitor at the output of opamp. Now,  I removed 0.1uF from output to ground and connected 100K in feedback still not getting the output. Opamp input pin is still influencing the voltage divider junction. Any suggestion on what next should I try ?

Comment: The device may now be damaged. Have you thought about replacing it @Brt <-- if you read the data sheet it warns you about using feedback resistors below 50 kohm with a specific example that talks about over-stressing the input diodes <-- see pg 12 and note that the absolute maximum input current is +/- 10 mA. I expect your original circuit may well have exceeded that value.

Comment: @Andyaka Thanks. I replaced the board with new IC and still the behaviour is same. Not getting expected output. Any idea what should I try next ?

Comment: Sorry, I can't see anything else that is wrong @Brt

Comment: @Andyaka Thanks for the answer. It is working now with new OPAMP. You were right that OPAMP was damaged. I took completely fresh board and it's working. Thanks again.